# Live bound submit does not point at element in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, submit, jquery-events

Running the following code, I expect to see the relative forms, so I can extract information from them. Instead, `this` points to the document.

I assume it is related to using a live binding, is there a work around?

```
 $('.form_one').add('.form_two').live('submit',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log($(this));
    })
```

Comment: 1) `live` is deprecated, use `on` instead. 2) Why are you `add`ing '.form_two'? You can write this as `$('.form_one, .form_two').on...`

Comment: If the forms aren't being added dynamically, you can write this as `$('.form_one, .form_two').submit(function()...`

Comment: `on` hasn't been perfect in my experience. I may be using it incorrectly, but if you replace `live` with `on` in this instance, it does not work in chrome.

Comment: The forms are both being added dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `live()` is a shortcut for delegating an event handler to the highest level DOM element - `document` - which is why the scope of `this` points there.

As a workaround you should use `$(e.target)` to get the element which raised the event.

Also, `live()` has been deprecated, you should be using `delegate()` or `on()` if you are using jQuery 1.7+.

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2QB9a/)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/ZBaWd/ will demonstrate how to use the `on` handler.

```
<div id="container"></div>​

var cont = $("#container");

// Note that I'm attaching it to container and not the forms themselves. 
// Then, as an additional parameter, I provide the selector "form" so that
// `on` is only fired for "form" elements that "submit" and are children of "#container"
$("#container").on("submit", "form", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this));
});


$("<form>").addClass("form_one").append("<button type='submit'>Submit 1</button>").appendTo(cont);
$("<form>").addClass("form_two").append("<button type='submit'>Submit 2</button>").appendTo(cont);
```